# Why would people vote to close their own question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, closed-questions

I have noticed this a couple times now. Personally I would

1. edit to get it reopened,
2. delete it if I realize it was legitimately a bad question, or
3. stand by my case that it was a good question to begin with.

Is there a rational for voting to close your own question?

Answer (score 3):

I personally voted to close some of my questions on other sites of the network. In particular I closed one recently as duplicate. I saw no value in deleting it because it might help the next person that would search for that kind of question and eventually find mine and not the duplicate (yes, it can happen, depending on the searchwords).

Also, deleting bad questions (or answers) is not something we should do indiscriminately, also bad posts have a value: they show new members what not to do here. If we continuously purge all "bad" (who determines if something is bad then? just a negative vote count?) content we might give the impression that this community is perfect, but we wouldn't be honest.

Comment: Our goal is to only have good content, and we self-police towards that. Leaving bad content just so that we look don't look perfect seems counter to that goal.

Comment: @Lnafziger my point is not to confuse "bad" with "wrong". I have a feeling this distinction is sometimes lost and "wrong" content is deleted as "bad", while to me it should be considered "good" because it teaches what NOT to do (or what is not true), that is equally important to it "right" counterpart.

Comment: Well, your answer refers to "bad" content, hence my comment.  :)

Comment: @Lnafziger point taken.

Answer (score 0):

I close my own question when I have 4 close votes. Somebody else is going to do it anyways.

Comment: Or you can edit the question to fit the scope of the site.